# Symfony i18n coupled to VueJS

Tags: vue.js, symfony, translation, vue-i18n

I am currently working on a project which is based on Symfony with parts in Vue.js.

Currently the translation of Symfony parts is managed with its internal module which uses .xlf files

For Vue.Js parts I thought I used Vue i18n. However, it does not handle .xlf files, so you should have 2 separate translation files.

Despite my research I can not find anything that could allow to have only one common file for the translation.

Comment: Symphony (CMS) or Symfony (framework)? They're different.

Comment: Symphony framework

Comment: Do you mean Symfony, with an 'f' and not 'ph'?

Comment: yes Symfony with an 'f'

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look at BazingaJsTranslationBundle: https://github.com/willdurand/BazingaJsTranslationBundle, and this issue https://github.com/willdurand/BazingaJsTranslationBundle/issues/276 if you use Webpack.

Another solution is to use a separate translation file for the frontend part, depending on how different is your frontend from your backend.